# How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac {3^h-1} {h}=\ln3$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How is

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {3^h-1} {h}=\ln3$$

evaluated?

Comment: are you sure you want $h \to \infty$? I think you want $h \to 0$. Then recall [de l'Hôpital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%F4pital's_rule) - the third example given in Wikipedia carries out the details.

Comment: my bad. Yes it is $h\to 0$

Comment: The limit is already in the form $\displaystyle{\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}}$; if you know how to find the derivative, there's no reason to use l'Hôpital.

Comment: @Theo Buehler: yes, i got it. So, is it something like pre-defined relation right.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: i did not get how to solve in that manner and so finding for an alternative.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand these last two comments. Are you asking why $f(h) = 3^{h}$ has derivative $f'(h) = \log{3}\cdot 3^{h}$?

Comment: no, i know that derivative of $3^h=3^h.ln3$. But i'm trying to figure it out how to slove it by $1^{st}$ order derivation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are at least two ways of doing this: Either you can use [de l'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%F4pital%27s_rule), and as I pointed out in the comments the third example on Wikipedia gives the details.

I think a better way of doing this (and Jonas seems to agree, as I saw after posting) is to write $f(h) = 3^{h} = e^{\log{3}\cdot h}$ and write the limit as $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}$$ and recall the definition of a derivative. What comes out is $f'(0) = \log{3}$.

Comment: changing the function and solving seems clear for me.

Comment: @amul28: ok, very good, then.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the fact that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x=1$ is usually shown before the definition of derivative in the introductory courses. Therefore the second solution is accessible even to students that haven't heard of derivatives yet and are studying limits.

Comment: @Martin: Very good point. But it doesn't hurt pointing out that it comes down to taking the derivative of a very common function, does it?

Comment: Following up on Martin's comment, if you wanted to reduce it to the limit with $e$ instead of $3$, you could use $\displaystyle{\frac{3^h-1}{h}=\frac{e^{h\ln(3)}-1}{h}=\ln(3)\cdot\frac{e^{h\ln(3)}-1}{h\ln(3)}=\ln(3)\cdot\frac{e^t-1}{t}}$, where $t=h\ln(3)$ goes to $0$ as $h$ does.

Answer (score 5):

The result can also be obtained using $\int_a^b {e^x \,dx}  = e^b  - e^a$ (for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$). Indeed, for any $h \neq 0$ it holds
$$
\frac{{3^h  - 1}}{h} = \frac{{\int_0^{(\ln 3)h} {e^u \,du} }}{h},
$$
and hence (since $x \mapsto e^x$ is continuous and $e^0=1$)
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{3^h  - 1}}{h} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{\int_0^{(\ln 3)h} {1\,du} }}{h} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{(\ln 3)h}}{h} = \ln 3.
$$

Comment: Recall the convention $\int_a^b {f(x)\,dx}  =  - \int_b^a {f(x)\,dx} $.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a  philological answer, this limit must be proved only by means of the definition of $x \mapsto a^x$. Of course it is the definition of the derivative of this function at $x_0=0$, and *therefore* you should not use De l'Hospital's rule: how can you compute a derivative if you do not know how to compute the *same* derivative?

These limits are always troublesome, since most of us do not learn a *rigorous* definition of the exponential function *before* computing elementary derivatives. That's why the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}=1
$$
is a *fundamental limit*: it is so hard to prove without a circular reasoning that calculus teachers take it for granted.

However, if you do not remember the final result, any tool is welcome, provided it gives you the correct answer!

Comment: Am I right in my proof?

Comment: Yes. It is also possible to note that $$\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\frac{e^{x \log a}-1}{x}$$ and multiply+divide by $\log a$.

Comment: How is *philology* (with phi-, not phy-) related to the question?

Answer (score 2):

This is such a basic limit that might as well be built up before the derivative, so I think the L'Hospital or derivative had better be avoided, and the following proof is necessary:

We prove that $\lim_{x\to0}\,(a^x-1)/x=\ln a$.

First we prove that $\lim_{x\to0}\,x/\log_a(1+x)=\ln a$.

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log_a(1+x)}x=\lim_{x\to0}\log_a(1+x)^{1/x}=\log_ae$$

(Can you prove that $\lim_{x\to0}(1+x)^{1/x}=e$ and $\log$ is continuous?)

So

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac x{\log_a(1+x)}=\ln a$$

In your problem, let $y=a^x-1$, and $x\to0$ (and never $=0$), we have $y\to0$ (and never $=0$), so $(a^x-1)/x=y/\log_a(1+y)\to\ln a$.

Comment: Why should the limit of $(1+x)^{1/x}$ be considered as more elementary than the limit of $\log(1+x)/x$?

Comment: @did As far as I know, most calculus book bases the properties of $e^x$ in derivative and integration on $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+x)^{1/x}$. More precisely, firstly we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n$ exists, which is the definition of $e$. Secondly, we can show that $(1+1/x)^x\to e$ as $x\to+\infty$ and $x\to-\infty$. For $x>0$, we have $(1+1/r)^l\le(1+1/x)^x\le(1+l)^r$, where $l=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $r=\lceil x\rceil$.

Comment: @did The word *should* seems offensive, so I change a word.

Comment: Sorry but this is not very convincing. The construction of real powers of positive real numbers seem to be based on, hence to be **less** elementary than, the log and exp functions.

Comment: @did But the derivative (say, $d(e^x)=e^xdx$) is no *less* elementary than $\log$ and $\exp$ functions.

Comment: ?? (Anyway, I think I stated the remark I wanted to state, so all is well.)

Comment: @did Well, I wrote this answer because I found that most answers here depended on the derivative formula $D(e^x)=e^x$, but I thought it might as well be avoided because $D(e^x)=e^x$ is proved by this problem. $D(e^x)=e^x$ is what I really meant the property of $e^x$, which is not elementary.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{3^h-1}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h\log 3}-1}{h}$. Now expansion of $e^{h\log 3}=1+\frac{h\log 3}{1!}+\frac{h^2(\log 3)^2}{2!}\cdots \implies \frac{e^{h\log 3}-1}{h}=\log 3+\frac{h(\log 3)^2}{2!}\cdots \implies \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h\log 3}-1}{h}=\log 3+0+0+\cdots = \log 3$ Hence, $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{3^h-1}{h}=\log 3$.

Answer (score -1):

Using the formula
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {a^x-1} {x}=\ln a,$$
we have for $a = 3$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {3^h-1} {h}=\ln 3.$$

Comment: -1. This precludes the desired result.